# What exactly is 动宾短语?

Tags: grammar

What exactly is 动宾短语?

1. Is it structure with no subject like 学汉语对人有好处。
2. Or is it part of a pivotal sentence what I have seen on some books.

兼语句：用兼语短语充当谓语的主谓句。其主要特点有：它的谓语
由一个动宾短语和一个主谓短语套接而成；动宾短语中的动词通常是使
令性动词。如： “叫、让‘派、使、请、教、劝、命令、禁止、任命、号
召、选举”等等。有是还用“有”。如：
A 我请周恩来同志来解释。
B 你让他下午到我办公室来一下。
C 蔚蓝的天宇中正有一群大雁飞过。

If you have a link with explanation in English or Spanish I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

兼语 is a structure where VO & SV combine to form V(O/S)V.

e.g.

让他（VO）+他吃饭（SV）=让他吃饭（兼语句式）

兼语 is inherited from Classical Chinese, ans is still common today.

e.g.

权即遣肃行。（《资治通鉴》）

Often we can omit (O/S) if the context permits:

权即遣行。

计未定，求人可使报秦者。（《史记•廉颇蔺相如列传》）

EDIT:

It's clear that 动宾短语 is Verb-Object Phrase~

（孙）权即遣（鲁）肃行

孙权 immediately send 鲁肃 to go (to build up alliance).

Comment: But what is 动宾短语。and where is it used¿.  I know what a pivotal sentence is.

Comment: “权即遣肃行” makes no sense to me. Is it some kind of Old Chinese for 权力部门将我遣返回国？？

Comment: Hola! Mira https://fanyi.baidu.com/#zh/en/%E5%8A%A8%E5%AE%BE%E7%9F%AD%E8%AF%AD por 动宾短语

Comment: @Pedroski translation updated

Comment: Thanks, I was puzzled!

Answer (score 0):

动宾短语 is a phrase (短语) that is made up of a verb (动) and its object (宾).

The main sentence structure of Chinese is SVO (Subject - Verb - Object), and the VO part is a 动宾短语.